# How to connect to a local database using DMX ZONE extentions

Tags: sql-server, database, dreamweaver

I am new to database work so please bear with me.

I'm using Dreamweaver and just installed DMXzone Database Connector ASP.NET

I need to define a local database connection but not sure how to go about it.

Basic settings the DMX extension is requesting are:

- Name:               sp_local
- Database Type:      SQL_Server
- Server Address:     NOT SURE
- Database:           NOT SURE
- Username: Dont think I need
- Password: Dont think I need

I am confused on how I would set this up on my local site.  Do I have to create tables or something to be in a file to reference? Or am I just trying to define a folder to use? Is there something special about a database file/location?

Also when I go to transfer to remote site am I just bringing the same file structure I create here over?

I'm also not sure what settings to use in the above to connect fields.

Thanks, and sorry for not know much.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a SQL Server to connect to? That's probably step 1, before connecting to it.

Comment: I do, well installed, but never did anything after that.  Ill find some tutorials. So when I set it up , something is created that I can connect to?

Comment: Yes, when you install SQL Server (not SSMS, which is an IDE but it's very useful) it creates a number of Windows services on that machine. This is your server. Then you can connect to it (easy to test the connection using SSMS as that can be installed with SQL Server). Once SQL Server is installed, you can create a Database on that server. At that point you should be able to connect using this extension.

Comment: Depending on how you configured the SQL Server install, you may need to input a Username/Password. If you are using Windows Auth, most likely it will auto connect using your Windows credentials. That is my assumption based on how most programs work (since I haven't used this dreamweaver extension I can't be sure).

Comment: Ok excellent, So I set up a basic DB "sp_local" and  created a simple userName / password table.  Pretty straight forward.  So now that is saved on my com.  So what would the :Server Address" be?

Comment: Im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.  Im checking the settings on sp_local now. Prob just says it somewhere. I tried something like this, A-T7500\SQLEXPRESS - got a 500 Internal Error

Comment: Try with `(local)` or the name of your computer. When you installed it would have asked you for the "Instance name", but it's not required. If you gave your server an instance name, you will need to use the format `computername\instancename` it's going to be the big WORD at the top next to the little server icon if you're in SSMS. Or whatever you put in the Server Name: field when you connected.